# Razor view errors not displaying source code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Whenever an error is thrown in my Razor view (.cshtml), I get a yellow screen that states

> The source code that generated this
>   unhandled exception can only be shown
>   when compiled in debug mode. To enable
>   this, please follow one of the below
>   steps, then request the URL:

It then says to either set the `<@ Page Debug="true">` in the view or set the `<compilation debug="true">` in the web.config.

I checked my web.config and the `<compilation debug="true">` is already set. To exhaust other options, I tried adding it to all the `web.config` files in the view folders, but no change.

I also checked that the projects are being compiled as `Debug` and not `Release`. Any thoughts as to why the source code where the error is being thrown is not being displayed?

**Edit:** My application was updated from ASP.NET MVC 2 to MVC 3.

Comment: Does this work when you create a brand new ASP.NET MVC application using the default Visual Studio template?

Comment: No. I forgot to mention that I upgrade my app from ASP.NET MVC 2 to MVC 3.

Comment: @Omar, so when you create a brand new ASP.NET MVC 3 application you are still not getting the source code?

Comment: Sorry - when I create a new MVC 3 application, I am able to see the source code for the error. The issue seems to be with this specific application.

Comment: Was it working before the upgrade?

Comment: Yes, prior to the upgrade I was able to see where an error occurred in the view's source code.

Comment: @Omar, would it be possible to send me the application so that I can see what's wrong. You could strip all code and leave just the backbone illustrating the problem (a controller action throwing an exception)?

Comment: Turns out it was trust-level issue. Thanks for the time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently source errors are not displayed when the trust level is set to medium.

I forgot to remove `<trust level="medium" />` from the web.config file after I was done testing in medium trust.

Answer (score -1):

```
1)
source errors does not appear if you do not insert
customErrors mode="Off"
and
compilation debug="true"
in your web.config
2)
when you're in medium trust you can use mvc3 provided you :
cast your return view(xxx) to return view((Object)xxx)
or, in vb: return view(xxx) to return DirectCast(view(xxx), Object) 
and
 Return View(model) to Return View((Object)model)
 or  to Return View(DirectCast(model, Object))

and
you do not use @ViewBag
```